# N permutations of only some elements in a vector

Tags: r, vector, permutation, simulation

Can someone please help me with a function or command in `RStudio` that permutes only some elements in a vector. So far I tried `runif()`, `sample()`, and `replicate()` but none allowed me to do what I trully needed.

What I currently have is:

1. A fixed vector drawn from theory `rc1<-c(8,4,2,10,5,6,9,6,1,3)` This vector will be used later to computer `spearman` correlations.
2. A vector from which to draw n-samples of permutations `y <-c(8,4,2,10,5,6,9,6,1,3)`

I would like the permutations to apply only to some elements of the y vector. For example:

`y1[**8**,6,5,7,2,10,9,4,1, **3**]`
`y2[**8**,2,5,10,4,7,9,1,6, **3**]`

This procedure should be repeated as many times as necessary, say n=100.
Finally, I would like to compute `spearman` correlations between vector rc1 and each of the permuted y vectors and eventually have one average correlation coefficient and the associated standard deviation.

Thank you in advance!
A complete beginner here and in R

Comment: Welcome to the site! Thank you for taking the time to make your question clear and reproducible!

Comment: Thank you! I already love this extremely helpful community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a little function that allows you to feed in your vector and the positions within that vector you wish to permute. It will just shuffle the indexes of the vector that you want to shuffle using `sample`

```r
permute_partial <- function(vec, indexes)
{
  keepers <- seq_along(vec)
  keepers[indexes] <- sample(indexes)
  vec[keepers]
}
```

So, for example, if you want 20 replicates of your vector, you could do:

```
y   <- c(8, 4, 2, 10, 5, 6, 9, 6, 1, 3)

t(replicate(20, permute_partial(y, 2:9)))
#>       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
#>  [1,]    8    4    6    2    6   10    5    9    1     3
#>  [2,]    8    6    9    2    5    1    4   10    6     3
#>  [3,]    8    2    4    9    6    6   10    5    1     3
#>  [4,]    8    5    2    6    9    1    6   10    4     3
#>  [5,]    8    4    6   10    6    1    5    2    9     3
#>  [6,]    8    9    4    6    5   10    2    1    6     3
#>  [7,]    8    2    9    4    1    6   10    6    5     3
#>  [8,]    8    6    1    5    9   10    2    6    4     3
#>  [9,]    8    5    4   10    9    6    1    6    2     3
#> [10,]    8    6   10    1    4    2    6    5    9     3
#> [11,]    8    4    6   10    9    2    5    6    1     3
#> [12,]    8   10    1    9    5    6    6    4    2     3
#> [13,]    8    6    2    6   10    9    4    1    5     3
#> [14,]    8    2    5    6    4   10    1    9    6     3
#> [15,]    8    6    9   10    6    4    2    1    5     3
#> [16,]    8   10    9    5    1    6    4    6    2     3
#> [17,]    8   10    6    9    1    2    5    6    4     3
#> [18,]    8   10    6    5    9    2    1    4    6     3
#> [19,]    8   10    2    6    9    4    1    6    5     3
#> [20,]    8    9    2    5   10    6    6    1    4     3
```

Now you can also replicate many samples using `sapply` to get a vector of all the Spearman correlations:

```r
set.seed(1)
y   <- c(8, 4, 2, 10, 5, 6, 9, 6, 1, 3)
rc1 <- c(8, 4, 2, 10, 5, 6, 9, 6, 1, 3)

result <- sapply(1:100, function(x) cor(rc1, permute_partial(y, 2:9), 
                                        method = "spearman"))

result
#>   [1]  0.167682927 -0.167682927  0.073170732 -0.192073171  0.277439024
#>   [6]  0.317073171  0.112804878  0.015243902  0.042682927 -0.189024390
#>  [11]  0.518292683  0.167682927  0.719512195 -0.457317073  0.091463415
#>  [16] -0.268292683  0.399390244  0.329268293  0.103658537  0.911585366
#>  [21] -0.451219512  0.118902439 -0.231707317 -0.039634146 -0.125000000
#>  [26]  0.021341463  0.527439024 -0.250000000  0.268292683  0.112804878
#>  [31] -0.091463415  0.682926829  0.435975610  0.707317073 -0.240853659
#>  [36]  0.182926829  0.088414634 -0.100609756  0.210365854  0.469512195
#>  [41]  0.356707317  0.182926829 -0.560975610  0.091463415  0.253048780
#>  [46]  0.466463415 -0.009146341  0.054878049  0.371951220  0.667682927
#>  [51]  0.911585366 -0.036585366  0.655487805  0.414634146 -0.073170732
#>  [56]  0.225609756 -0.009146341  0.134146341  0.435975610 -0.012195122
#>  [61] -0.091463415  0.509146341 -0.201219512  0.158536585 -0.036585366
#>  [66]  0.716463415 -0.463414634 -0.417682927  0.545731707 -0.015243902
#>  [71] -0.006097561  0.036585366  0.079268293 -0.338414634  0.493902439
#>  [76]  0.414634146  0.466463415  0.503048780 -0.289634146  0.185975610
#>  [81] -0.371951220 -0.228658537  0.201219512  0.414634146 -0.225609756
#>  [86]  0.329268293  0.551829268  0.115853659  0.112804878 -0.103658537
#>  [91] -0.003048780  0.219512195 -0.073170732 -0.320121951  0.082317073
#>  [96]  0.390243902  0.280487805  0.344512195 -0.198170732  0.009146341
```

Which looks like this:

```
hist(result)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-06-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you Allan! I notice however that the resulting data is drawn from under a normal distribution and not from a uniform distribution (rectangular) as I was hoping for. Also this is not quite the final version of simulated data I was looking for.
Is it possible to have, say, 10 rows (representing the elements of the vector) x 100 collumns (representing the 100 permutations)?

Comment: @StanciuAdrian perhaps I didn't explain too well. The simulated data is used inside the `sapply` function to generate the Spearman correlations. I have modified my answer to show that the samples can be drawn using the function at the top of my answer. You will see that for the example I have drawn 20 samples. However, when you draw 100 samples like this and run the correlations, you get a normal distribution, not a uniform distribution. This is what you would expect from the central limit theorem.

Comment: this is perfect! Exactly what I was hoping for. Thank you so much for your quick help and understanding for my beginner's undertanding level.

Answer (score 2):

Create a logical vector of the positions to be fixed. Fill in the fixed positions and then the permuted positions

```
set.seed(42)
fix <- c(TRUE, rep(FALSE, 8), TRUE)  # Fix first and last position
rcsam <- rep(NA, length(rc1))        # Empty vector
rcsam[fix] <- rc1[fix]               # Fixed positions
rcsam[!fix] <- sample(rc1[!fix])     # Permuted values
rcsam
# [1]  8  4  6  1  9  2  5 10  6  3
```

You can create a function to repeat this process:

```
fixsam <- function(x, fix) {
    y <- rep(NA, length(x))
    y[fix] <- x[fix]
    y[!fix] <- sample(x[!fix])
    return(y)
}

rcsam <- replicate(100, fixsam(x=rc1, fix=fix))
rcsam[, 1:5]    # Each column is a sample.

      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 [1,]    8    8    8    8    8
 [2,]    5    2    6    6    1
 [3,]   10    6    5    5    4
 [4,]    9    4    6    9    2
 [5,]    6    9    4    1    6
 [6,]    2   10   10    6    9
 [7,]    6    6    9    2   10
 [8,]    1    1    1   10    5
 [9,]    4    5    2    4    6
[10,]    3    3    3    3    3
```

To compute spearman correlations use `apply`:

```
cors <- apply(rcsam, 2, cor, y=rc1, method="spearman")
summary(cors)
#    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
# -0.6433 -0.1059  0.1585  0.1715  0.3880  0.9604
```

Comment: Indeed, this is what I was looking for. But as Gregor mentions, I am looking to repeat this  as many times as my analytic procedure requires. For now, say 100 times.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've illustrated creating a function to repeat this as many times as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Someone has already given a neat answer, if you want to generalize the process, perhaps you can write a function to do this.

```
rc1<-c(8,4,2,10,5,6,9,6,1,3) 
y <-c(8,4,2,10,5,6,9,6,1,3)
fix_index <- c(1,10) ## index of the fixed elements

spear_corr <- function(rc1,y,fix_index){
  
  y_size <- length(y) 
  permute_index <- c(1:y_size)[-fix_index] ## index of to be permuted elements

  permute_num <- length(permute_index) ## 
  permute_y <- y
  permute_y[permute_index] <- sample(x=y[permute_index],size = permute_num,replace = FALSE) ## a new vector with permuted elements
  
  corrleation <- cor(rc1,permute_y,method = "spearman") ## find spearman correlation
  
  return(corrleation)
}

spear_corr(rc1,y,fix_index)

## repeat this 100 times
corr_vector <- vector()
for (i in 1:100) {
  corr_vector[i] <- spear_corr(rc1,y,fix_index)
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for you help! Now I have alternative ways in dealing with this.